# android:background="" is giving error

Tags: android, android-ndk

I don't what to give any background to activity. When I leave this property blank, it gives me an error.

And I have tried using `@null` as a value but it shows black background.

Can any one guide me, how to make it transparent?

Comment: Do you want the whole application transparent or just this activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this using styles. In `res/values/styles.xml`, have a theme definition:

```
<style name="MyTheme">
  <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

As far as I know, you must set windowIsFloating, otherwise the runtime will not draw a translucent background (presumably for performance reasons... but I have seen this behavior change between different platform releases, so you could first try without it).

Then set the theme for your Activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name="..." android:theme="@style/MyTheme" ... />
```

That should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

For an Activity you can set the theme to translucent in the onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);}
```

You could also do this in the xml file like in this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_ui_themes-t4367.html).

Comment: it is trasnparent but showing white background can i change that transparent background to some other color or black??

Comment: As its translucent it will be clear but whatever activity is in the background is what you will see underneath

Comment: yes you are right but i want  previous activity then tranparent background between both and new activity.
mean i could see through black transparent color previous activity.

any idea??

Comment: I'm sorry but I dont understand what you mean?

You want to start a new activity over yand activity you already have on screem and be able to see through this new activity?